# UserControl Location in WPF

Tags: .net, wpf, wpf-controls

I am new in WPF, I created a new UserControl MyUserControl.

Now I am surprised: the UserContol does not have a location.

How can I read (by code) myUserControl1.`Location` in the parent container?

I explain:

I have some Dots (UserControls) that the user can drag in a panel. Actually, I am not sure what kind of Panel this will be... Perhaps Grid.

Now, these dots should be linked with a Line.

Actually, I have a `Dot.Head` and `Dot.Queue` properties (also Dots). So, when a Head or Queue is added, I need to dinamically create a link (Line) between them [A]-----[B]. This for this Line I search the Start and End points to set.

Control XAML:

```
<UserControl x:Class="LinePlan.Stop"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
    mc:Ignorable="d" d:DesignHeight="21" d:DesignWidth="80">
    <Canvas>
        <Path Fill="LightBlue" Width="16" Height="16">
            <Path.Data>
                <EllipseGeometry x:Name="Dot" Center="8,8" 
                    RadiusX="4" RadiusY="4"/>
            </Path.Data>
        </Path>
        <TextBlock x:Name="StopText" Text="Eiffel Tower" Canvas.Left="16"/>
    </Canvas>
</UserControl>
```

Code:

```
public partial class Stop : UserControl
{
    private Stop head;
    private Stop tail;
    private LineGeometry headLine;
    private LineGeometry queueLine;

    public Stop()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public Stop Head
    {
        get { return head; }
        set
        {
            if (head != value)
            {
                head = value;
                if (head == null) 
                {
                    if (headLine != null)
                        headLine = null;
                }
                else
                {
                    headLine = new LineGeometry();
                    headLine.StartPoint = head.DotPosition;
                    headLine.EndPoint = this.DotPosition;

                    // ?? Add this line to the parent
                }

            }
        }
    }

    public Stop Tail
    {
        get { return tail; }
        set { tail = value; }
    }

    public Point DotPosition
    {
        get
        {
            double x = Canvas.GetLeft(this) + this.Dot.Center.X;
            double y = Canvas.GetTop(this) + this.Dot.Center.Y;
            return new Point(x, y);
        }
        set
        {
            Canvas.SetLeft(this, value.X - this.Dot.Center.X);
            Canvas.SetTop(this, value.Y - this.Dot.Center.Y);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The word "queue" is a *faux-ami*... I think the word you're looking for is "tail" ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The WPF layout system doesn't use absolute positioning, unless you're placing your controls on a container that supports absolute positioning (typically a `Canvas`). If you're using a `Canvas`, you can get or set the position of the control using the `Canvas.Left`, `Canvas.Right`, `Canvas.Top` and `Canvas.Bottom` attached properties:

```
double x = Canvas.GetLeft(myControl);
double y = Canvas.GetTop(myControl);
```

Now, if you want the actual location of the control (relative to its parent), you can use the `VisualTreeHelper.GetOffset` method:

```
Vector offset = VisualTreeHelper.GetOffset(myControl);
double x = offset.X;
double y = offset.Y;
```

Comment: According to your explanation, I think the only candidate panel for you is Canvas...

Comment: I added the real code... NAN is returned as positions, at least in design mode...

Comment: I tested in runtime too... see the code above: both `this.GetValue(Canvas.LeftProperty)` and `Canvas.GetLeft(this)` returns NAN ...

Comment: The Left and Top attached properties only have a value if you set it explicitly. If you want the actual value, use VisualTreeHelper.GetOffset

Answer (score 1):

Elements (like user controls) are normally placed in panels in WPF. Depending on which panel you are using the panel may add some attached properties to the user control. If the user control is placed in a `Canvas` it will get the attached properties `Left`, `Top`, `Right` and `Bottom`. However, if the user control is placed in a `Grid` it will get the attached properties `Row` and `Column` (and some more). Other panels like `StackPanel` will not attach any properties. There is no such thing as a universal user control location.

[Panels Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms754152.aspx)

[Attached Properties Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms749011.aspx)

Assuming that you are using a `Canvas` as your panel you can access the attached `Left` and `Top` properties like this:

```
Double x = Canvas.GetLeft(myUserControl1);
Double y = Canvas.GetTop(myUserControl1);
```